# Gmail putting spacing between images in HTML email

Tags: gmail, email

I have created HTML emailer with images, but emailer is not displayed properly in gmail. Pleae help me.

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged "knapsack-problem"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `display:block;` to the style of each image. It's a pain!